# Definition of a norm infinity

Tags: calculus, operator-theory

I have $u:\mathbb{R}^3\times(0,\infty)\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R}^3\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Which means the following?:

$\|u(\cdot,t)\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)}$,

and

$\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)}$

I have no the definitions.

Thanks!

Comment: $\lVert \,\cdot\,\rVert_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)}$ is the essential-sup norm.

Answer (score 1):

To take the second one first:
$$\|g\|_{L^\infty(\mathbb{R}^3)}=\operatorname{ess sup}\limits_{x\in\mathbb{R}^3}|g(x)|.$$
That mysterious thing on the right is the \emph{essential supremum}. If $g$ is continuous, it is just the ordinary supremum of all the function values. Otherwise, it is the smallest number $M$ so that $|g(x)|\le M$ for almost all $x$.

For the first one, $u(\cdot,t)$ means fix $t$, and consider the function $x\mapsto u(x,t)$. In other words, $u(x,t)$ considered as a function of $x$ alone, with $t$ held constant. Then take the essential supremum norm of this.